# Eliminar registros repetidos en un select en Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

tengo el siguiente select

```
SELECT correo_persona
FROM tb_extintores
INNER JOIN tb_cliente_normal
ON rut_cliente = rut_persona
WHERE fecha_vencimiento BETWEEN '2018-09-11' AND '2018-12-11'
```

que trae devuelta correos de clientes. pero en ocaciones el correo de un mismo cliente se repite mas de 1 ves y necesito que solo se extraiga un coreo por cliente.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT correo_persona 
FROM tb_extintores 
INNER JOIN tb_cliente_normal 
ON rut_cliente= rut_persona 
WHERE fecha_vencimiento BETWEEN '2018-09-11' AND '2018-12-11'
```

Mediante `DISTINCT` obtendremos solamente 1 valor por cada repetición.

> Fuente: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp

Comment: Ojo que puede haber una sutileza en lo solicitado por el op. Dice que quiere **un** correo por cliente, y esto entrega sólo correos diferentes. Pero si un cliente tiene más de un correo distinto, entonces aparecerán todos sus correos distintos, no sólo 1

Comment: actualmente solo guardo un correo por cliente.. gracias.